# LINQ perform select and insert in single query

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6, .net-core-2.0

I am working on Entity Framework 6 in C# .NET CORE 2.0 application. I have requirement to get role id from database where roleName = x and add role reference to user as in one: many table

I want to avoid 2 trip to database, I want to do in one go or in single Linq query

```
  UserDataModel userObj = new UserDataModel()
        {
            Id = fakeUserID,
            Name = "k1",
            Surname = "z",
            Email = "k.z@yahoo.co.uk",
            Roles = new List<UserRoleDataModel>
            {
                new UserRoleDataModel {
                    UserId = fakeUserID,
                    RoleId = Context.Roles.Where(roleName => roleName.Name == RoleName).Select(x=>x.Id)
                }
            }
        };

        Context.Add<UserModel>(userObj);
        Context.SaveChanges();
```

above code gives me error at RoleId
    refer in screen shot;

[image]

Comment: The answer from @ZaidMirza will fix the error, but you still make 2 trips to the database since the query on Roles will execute once you call First()  Short answer is no, you can't do this from EF, the only thing that you can do is write a stored procedure, which will do the things you want and then call it from EF

Answer (score 1):

Error because you are assigning `IQueryable` to a Property of type `Int` (I Assumed its `Int`). You should do this:

```
RoleId = Context.Roles.Where(roleName => roleName.Name == RoleName && roleName.Id==Id).Select(x=>x.Id).First();
```